# How to get letter from each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I have a HTML like this:

```
<ol style="list-style: lower-alpha">
    <li>First Line</li>
    <li>Second Line</li>
    <li>Third Line</li>
</ol>
```

which will results in:

```
a. First Line
b. Second Line
c. Third Line
```

How can I get `a` when click `First Line`, `b` when click `Second Line`........?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript method [**fromCharCode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) in this case:

```
$('li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
    });
});
```

`97` is the charcode of letter `a` and the loop will auto increase and give you the next letter.

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7AZAb/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try [this(*DEMO)*](http://jsfiddle.net/tyL2e/) out,

**Concept:**

use [Index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the `index` of the clicked `li element`. 
see, `97` is the `ascii code` for the character of `'a'`. Say if you clicked on the `first li`, the `index()` will return `zero`. so (97+0) = 97 = 'a'. like this it'll display results for all the other elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ol li").click(function(){ 

        alert(String.fromCharCode(97 + $(this).index()));

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(95 + i);
    });
});
```